git diff returns no modified files when raising a pull request in branching strategy workflow
I’m working on setting up CI/CD pipelines for a batch project in GitHub using GitHub Actions. The project’s directory structure looks like this:
batch_project/
├── alpha/
│   ├── program_1.txt
│   ├── program_2.txt
│   └── program_3.txt
├── beta/
│   ├── program_1.txt
│   ├── program_2.txt
│   └── program_3.txt
├── gamma/
│   ├── program_1.txt
│   ├── program_2.txt
│   └── program_3.txt
└── .github/
    └── workflows/
        └── ci-cd.yml

Triggering:
Whenever there’s a code push in any of the programs in the alpha, beta, or gamma modules, the workflow should trigger builds and deployments specific to those changes.
Problem:
Everything works well except when I raise a pull request from a feature/* or release/* branch to the main branch. The workflow step meant to list the modified files returns empty, even though I’ve made changes in the pull request.
Here’s the part of my workflow that isn’t working as expected:
MODIFIED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only origin/$BASE_BRANCH..${{ github.sha }})


Try printing out the commit IDs (perhaps with git rev-parse <ref>) of the following: origin/$BASE_BRANCH, ${{ github.sha }}. My guess is they'll end up being the same, and then you'll need to figure out why that is. The solution to your problem might be timing of when the script is run, or that you need to use a different variable.

Yes, both commit sha are same. Wondering why it is same as main branch and my source branch are different in the PR. There is a enough gap between PR job and merge job.

@TTT do we have better way to handle this scenario? DevOps process for batch projects ?

Base on docs:

The pull_request webhook event payload is empty for merged pull
requests and pull requests that come from forked repositories.


The value of GITHUB_REF varies for a closed pull request depending on
whether the pull request has been merged or not.
If a pull request
was closed but not merged, it will be
refs/pull/PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER/merge.
If a pull request was closed as a result of being merged, it will be the fully qualified ref of the branch it was merged into, for example /refs/heads/main.

Meaning, when the PR is in merge state, it's all main, and you can see that also on your output:
Base branch: main
Current branch: main
Base branch commit (main): bcf15d0f7bce60e77d71f501b9c105ea48c20ff3
Current branch commit (github.sha): bcf15d0f7bce60e77d71f501b9c105ea48c20ff3

There's no base branch info anymore, and sha you'll get is of main itself.
What you can do, and I can't test, but I believe will work, is:
git diff --name-only c05f017^ c05f017
For the second issue, if I understand correctly, the merges are happening very close to each other, and one take the changes of the other as well as its own.
Probably very delicate timing.
The solution I see is rebasing and pushing the branch before build-release, something like (Remember that I can't test it, and it's verbose for explanation purposes, it can be shrunk to one step):
jobs:
  rebase:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the target branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v4 # Change to 4 in general
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
          fetch-depth: 0
          clean: true

      - name: Checkout the current branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
          git checkout ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}

      - name: Rebase the current branch onto the target branch
        run: |
          git rebase ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}

      - name: Push the rebased branch
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          git push origin ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} --force

  build:
    needs: rebase
... 
# your workflow


This a new issue? Can you add it to the question so its easier to read? At the end as an additional issue from results

Updated the question. It is more of branching strategy for the batch project.

Edited with answer

Same issue - updated the question with results

Skip the checkout at the beginning of build after rebase

Error : fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git Error: Process completed with exit code 128. I have shallow checkout to have .git folder, but issue remain same.

Can you log diff right after rebase command? And reflog

Amazing! Can you edit my answer with the details? So it will help other when need
